# How do i control the space between the icon and text Materialize

Tags: html, css, icons, materialize

```
  <ul id="slide-out" class="side-nav fixed" >
      <div class="logo"><a href="#" class="brand-logo"><%= image_tag "logo.png", height:"auto",width:"120" %></a></div>
      <ul class="collapsible" data-collapsible="accordion">
        <li>
          <div class="collapsible-header" style="font-size: 15px"><i class="material-icons" style="font-size: 20px">send</i><span>Main</span></div>
          <div class="collapsible-body" style="background:blue" style="font-size: 15px">
            <ul>
            <a href=""> <li><<i class="material-icons" style="font-size: 20px">send</i> Message</a> </li>
            <a href=""><li><i class="material-icons" style="font-size: 20px">send</i> Scheduler</a> </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </ul>
    <ul>
```

> [image]

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on your problem?

Answer (score 0):

A fast hack can be to add some non-breaking spaces `&nbsp;` but I wouldn't recommend it. 
Else you can look for that particular class in the css file and modify the padding.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<span>` tag surrounding the icons and give a padding using style property.

```
<a href=""> <li><span style="padding-right: 5px"><i class="material-icons" style="font-size: 20px">send</i></span> Message</a> </li>
```